# Reproducing a picture

Tags: tikz-arrows, labels, node-connections

does any of you know how I can reproduce the following picture in latex? My main concerns are the labeled connecting arrows. Thanks in advance for your help.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 1):

It  can easily be done with `pstricks`, defining nodes at the relevant places, and linking them with a node connection:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

[John\textsubscript{[3.S\rnode{G}{G}.M]} managed-$\nu$ [\textsubscript{Fin P}PRO\textsubscript{[$\upphi$: \rnode{3}{3}.\rnode{SG}{SG}.M]-i}%
 Fin[\textsubscript{TP} \st{PRO}\textsubscript{[$\upphi$:3\rnode{S}{.S}G.M]-i} to stay healthy]]]%
 \psset{linejoin=1, linearc=0.05, arrows=->, arrowinset={0.1}, nodesep=3pt, angle=-90}\vskip 5ex
 \ncbar{G}{3}\nbput{\bfseries by predication}
 \ncbar{SG}{S}\nbput{\bfseries by movement}

Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bernard, unfortunately the solution you offered did not fully worked out. I get the structure, but not the connecting arrows and the label underneath.

Comment: How did you compile?

Comment: I am not sure, I understand your question, but I did copy and paste exactly what you have proposed into my overleaf project.

Comment: With pstricks (which is an interface between latex and postscript, either you compile with the chain `latex->dvi -> dvips -> pstopdf` or you compile with `xelatex --shell-escape`.

Comment: @Bernand it works when compiling with xelatex, I lost other parts of my project though. Is there any other possibility ?

Comment: In theory, you can try `pdflatex  --shell-escape` if you also load `pstricks-pdf`, but personally I can't make it work correctly (under MiKTeX). Other possibility, you can compile the code as a standalone file, and include the resulting .pdf as a graphic file.

Comment: thanks again for your efforts to help me. I have now solved the problem.

Comment: That's fine! :o)

Answer (score 1):

- Load the packages

  ```
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}% needed for \tikzmarknode
  ```
- Wrap the parts that should be the start or end of an arrow with the command

  ```
  \tikzmarknode{name}{part of text}
  ```
- Add a section

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \draw commands that use the names from \tikzmarknode
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```
- Run pdflatex at least twice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}% needed for \tikzmarknode
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% only used for arrow tip stealth'
\begin{document}

[John\textsubscript{\tikzmarknode{1}{[3.SG.M]}} managed-$\nu$
 [\textsubscript{Fin P}PRO
 \textsubscript{\tikzmarknode{2}{[$\phi$:3.SG.M]-i}}Fin
 [\textsubscript{TP} PRO\textsubscript{\tikzmarknode{3}{[$\phi$:3.SG.M]-i}}
 to stay healthy]]]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth']
  \draw[->] (1) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| node[below,pos=0.25]{\bfseries by predication} ([xshift=-5pt]2); 
  \draw[<-] (3) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| node[below,pos=0.25]{\bfseries by movement} ([xshift=5pt]2); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked !